# Laravel - Return with input from a dynamic select menu after validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4

I have a couple of select menus that are populated dynamically by selecting an option from another menu.

because these are populated dynamically, Laravel's withInput function does not return the data that was selected if the form does not pass validation.

Is there a way to return Input from dynamically created field data?

Here is my java script that builds the select menu

```
$('.admin-select').change(function() {

    $.getJSON("/locations/getlocationslist/"+$(this).val(), function(data) {

        var location = $('#location');
        location.empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            location.append("<option value='"+ element.id +"'>" + element.name + "</option>");
        });
        $.one(location.prepend("<option>- Select -</option>"));

    });
});
```

This is the function that gets the data for the menu:

```
public function getlocationslist($id)
{
    $company = Company::find($id); 
    $locations = $company->locations();
    return Response::make($locations->get(['id','name']));
}
```

In my users controllers store function I check validation:

```
$this->userNewForm->validate(Input::all());
```

Then the error handler:

```
App::error(function(Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException $exception, $code)
{
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($exception->getErrors());
});
```

Comment: Data is already in your form, can't you just return the errors and show them to your user?

Answer (score 0):

As the location select menu is dynamically created via AJAX the option isn't there for Laravel to preselect when it reloads the page.

However you can check if an option has been selected on page load for `.admin-select` and if it has then do the ajax call to refill the dynamic drop down and select the relevant option.